# how to run the query "GRANT FILE ON `only\_this\_db`.* TO user;"?

Tags: mysql

when we run:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO user;
```

all is fine, but ***.*** just means "in ALL DB + in ALL tables"

then how I can declare

```
user can run "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/path/backup.SQL' FROM `db_one`;"
```

but of course!, ONLY from database "db_one" not from "any_db"

Comment: The FILE privilege is a global privilege, not per-database. It just means that if you have access to a table, you can read/write that table from a file.

Comment: thanks @Barmar then the QUERY `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO user;` not degrade the security ?

Comment: No. They still have to have `SELECT` permission on the database before they can write to the file.